# How to reverse brackets in a single go using python?

Tags: python

My string is `this (that)` and I want to make it `this )that(`. But If I replace the `)` with `(` then when I replace the `(` with `)` then both of them changes.
I want to change this two in a single go so that the changed bracket doesn't get changed again. My string could have multiple open and close brackets in it.

Comment: What about switching `(` to `[` (or any other unused marker character) and then `)` to `(` and finally `[` to `)`

Comment: using a for loop it can be done. for c in s:
 if c=='(':
  r += ')'
 elif c==')':
  r+='('
 else:
  r+= c